# Get image path in CSS

Tags: css

I have a file Products.html and in the same directory, I have an image cook.jpg

How can i specify the url of the image in the file. I am trying this but it does not work print anything on the page

```
url ("cook.jpg");
```

Comment: More information is required.

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the image you specified is relative to where the CSS file is, not the HTML file.